# Drawing a line from UILabel to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to draw a line from the bottom center of a label to the top center of an image programmatically but after much googling i cant figure out how. I have a for loop that is creating the images and labels that they point to and so need to write it to fit within this loop so that it creates all the lines associated with their label/image and positions them accordingly.

Here is the loop:

```
    for i in 0..<hotspots.count {

        let hotspotImageButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        let hotspotTitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        let hotspotTextLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)

        hotspotImageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hotspotTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hotspotTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let whiteHotspotImage = UIImage(named: hotspots[i].image)?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

        hotspotImageButton.setImage(whiteHotspotImage, forState: .Normal)
        hotspotImageButton.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        hotspotTitleLabel.text = hotspots[i].title
        hotspotTextLabel.text = hotspots[i].text

        hotspotTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        hotspotTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13)
        hotspotTextLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        hotspotTextLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)


        standMapImage.addSubview(hotspotImageButton)
        standMapImage.addSubview(hotspotTitleLabel)
        standMapImage.addSubview(hotspotTextLabel)

        hotspotImageButton.snp_makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(standMapImage.snp_leadingMargin).multipliedBy(hotspots[i].hotspotXCoordinate)
            make.top.equalTo(standMapImage.snp_topMargin).multipliedBy(hotspots[i].hotspotYCoordinate)
            make.width.equalTo(standMapImage.snp_width).multipliedBy(0.1)
            make.height.equalTo(hotspotImageButton.snp_width)
        }

        hotspotTitleLabel.snp_makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(standMapImage.snp_leadingMargin).multipliedBy(hotspots[i].titleXCoordinate)
            make.top.equalTo(standMapImage.snp_topMargin).multipliedBy(hotspots[i].titleYCoordinate)
        }

        hotspotTextLabel.snp_makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerX.equalTo(hotspotTitleLabel.snp_centerX)
            make.top.equalTo(hotspotTitleLabel.snp_bottom).inset(-4)
        }

    }
```

[Picture of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcXuT.jpg)
[image]
Any help would be great as im fairly new to all of this and google didnt provide much for me.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you show in an image or drawing, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have linked an image for you. thanks

Comment: you can try bezier path to show that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This ...!

```
-(void)createLineFrom:(UILabel *)base andTo:(UIImageView*)view{

    CGPoint basePoint = CGPointMake(base.bounds.origin.x+base.bounds.size.width/2,base.bounds.origin.y+base.bounds.size.height/2);
    CGPoint bellonPoint = CGPointMake((view.frame.origin.x+view.frame.size.width/2),view.frame.origin.y+view.frame.size.height);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:basePoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:bellonPoint];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How do i write that in swift? Sorry, im very new to xcode and swift.

Comment: You can google it CGPoint , UIBezierPath , CAShapeLayer in swift

Answer (score 2):

Here is@srinivas n code in `swift` language

```
func createLineFrom(base: UILabel, andTo view: UIImageView) {
    var basePoint = CGPointMake(base.bounds.origin.x + base.bounds.size.width / 2, base.bounds.origin.y + base.bounds.size.height / 2)
    var bellonPoint = CGPointMake((view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width / 2), view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height)
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    path!.moveToPoint(basePoint)
    path!.addLineToPoint(bellonPoint)
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer.layer
    shapeLayer.path = path!.CGPath()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer!)
}
```

Try it